# Syntax for using declaration without variable

Tags: c#, using-statement

Consider a disposable with side effects in the constructor:

```
public class MyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public MyDisposable()
    {
        // Some side effects
        ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If I'm only interested in the side effects I can, in some method, use the class like so:

```
using var _ = new MyDisposable();
using var __ = new MyDisposable();
using var ___ = new MyDisposable();
```

Is there some syntax to avoid declaring the variables as they are unused? Something like:

```
using new MyDisposable();
using new MyDisposable();
using new MyDisposable();
```

I'm only interested in if there is such a syntax. I'm not looking for a way to restructure the code into a more sane approach.

Comment: So you mean `new MyDisposable().Dispose();`?

Comment: I mean, by your own admission this isn’t sane, so why would special syntax exist to support it?

Comment: what's the point of inventing that grammer, if possible?

Comment: @Sweeper Good point! Should work.

Comment: How about: `using (new MyDisposable()) {}`

Comment: @Wyck Perfectly fine as well.

Comment: Side effects are already a code smell, but being _only_ interested in size effects is the extreme version. You should definitely refactor to another solution, because this doesn't sound like a good design.

Comment: @JHBonarius I can think of an use here: C++-like scope locks. `public MyDisposable()  { Monitor.Enter(o); } public void Dispose(){ Monitor.Exit(o); }` That may come in useful in one form or another.

Comment: Another useful and valid side effect would be displaying the hourglass.

Comment: @PMF Why do you think it would be useful to enter and then immediately exit a monitor?  That sure doesn't sound useful.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Why do you think it'd be useful to set, and then immediately unset, a cursor?

Comment: @Servy: You would set the cursor, do some lengthy operation inside the using statement and finally restore the old cusor. Note the using var would also dispose at the end of the block and not immediately.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes But that's not what they're doing here.  They're specifically *not* doing anything between creating the disposable object and disposing of it.  Beyond that, they're specifically asking how to make it *impossible* for anything to be done during that time.

Comment: @Servy: the OP does not show a usage example, so we cannot tell.

Comment: @PMF C# has `lock() {}` for that for a long time now. IMHO using `using` blocks for side-effects is misusing a feature. A 'hack'. And (as we all know) that leads to unmaintainable code. I'm not convinced.

Comment: I believe C# 8.0's [using declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration) does not permit omitting the variable name.  I'm not certain but I believe there is also a _pattern-based using_ which permits the regular `using` block to be employed so long as the object implements a `Dispose` method, and doesn't have to implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

The using statement works without variable declation:

```cs
using (new MyDisposable()) {
    Console.WriteLine("in using");
}
```

You can test it with this class:

```cs
public class MyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose");
    }
}
```

and this console app:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Start");
using (new MyDisposable()) {
    Console.WriteLine("in using");
}
Console.WriteLine("End");
Console.ReadKey();
```

It prints:

> Start
> in using
> Dispose
> End